# On Mouseover need div to slide-up

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have a div in which the top is barely visible (Image #1), but on mouseover it slides up to where it will have some copy in it (Image #2). Then on mouseout / leave the div returns back to #1 position.

Any help is greatly appreciated

[Link to IMG of what I'm trying accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ12v.jpg)

Comment: Here is what I have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/dAj9S/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything work fine, just two little change and you are on the go!

First when you use stop, put write it like that : `stop(true);` the div will stop flickering.

Then, to be able to see a little red line, you just have to play with the height of `.default`  Note that if you change it in the CSS, you have to change it in the `animate()` too!

I personally set it to 15px will testing and it's a good value, see for yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/dAj9S/14/

Note that the way your are doing your animation will not be responsive. In other word, if your text have 2 lines, it will not work well. Your code is totally acceptable for someone who "dont get along" with jQuery. I am just pointing out a problem you may face later!

**EDIT:** As Ringo said in his answer, use `.hover()` instead of `.mouseover()` and `mouseout()`!

Comment: Your fiddle is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for... only thing is if you leave your mouse on the div for a second with the red box up and move your mouse, the red box kind acts weirdly. How could I fix that, as you have been a tremendous help to me.

Comment: That's in fact wierd, but I solved it by adding `overflow:hidden;` inside `#thumbFeatures .up-down` CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/dAj9S/17/

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Use hover() instead of mouseover() and mouseout().

Don't use delay(), use a setTimeout() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words... how can I had the div slightly visible when not "active"? -- if that makes sense

Comment: Why is using delay not ok?

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard jQuery functions like:

```
.slideUp()
```

(source: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)